# Background for popup is not displayed in Android

Tags: android, popup

I am a new android developer trying to write a simple contact book. When I select delete button it has to ask for a confirmation in a popup. But there is no background for popup. In my code I wrote the popup in a listener in the same parent activity.

[image]

```
    protected void delPopup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) DisplayContact.this
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sure,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
       yes_btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
        no_btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
       pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
       pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

       prepareListeners();
       buttonClick();
       mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    };
```

and the xml file goes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and A text view , 2 buttons
Can someone guide me what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background in popup is transparent by default. You must set background for your popup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#000000"

    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```